# building MUPDF for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

i'm new in using NDK and i want to build MUPDF library for my PDF Viewer project, i followed 
[Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project/8587527#8587527)  and also this [ReadMe.txt](http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/android/ReadMe.txt) and i encountered this errors:.

```
home@home-desktop:/$ ndk-build -C /home/home/Downloads/MUPDFlib/mupdf-0.9/android
make: Entering directory `/home/home/Downloads/MUPDFlib/mupdf-0.9/android'
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : mupdf <= mupdf.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_error.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_geometry.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_getopt.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_hash.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_memory.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_object.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_string.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_time.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_aes.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_arc4.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_md5.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_sha2.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_bbox.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_list.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_null.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_text.c
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:6:22: error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:7:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:8:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c: In function 'fz_text_extract_span':
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:215: error: 'FT_Face' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:215: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:215: error: for each function it appears in.)
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:215: error: expected ';' before 'face'
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:237: error: 'face' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:318: error: 'FT_Fixed' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:318: error: expected ';' before 'ftadv'
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:319: error: 'FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP' undeclared (first use in this    function)
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:319: error: 'FT_LOAD_NO_HINTING' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:319: error: 'FT_LOAD_IGNORE_TRANSFORM' undeclared (first use in this function)
jni/../../fitz/dev_text.c:324: error: 'ftadv' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfcore/__/__/fitz/dev_text.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/home/Downloads/MUPDFlib/mupdf-0.9/android'
home@home-desktop:/$
```

hope someone can help me here.

Comment: You can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project/8587527#8587527. I've put the step-by-step instructions how to build mupdf.

Answer (score 2):

In the `mupdf-0.9` folder run the command `make` before running `ndk-build` in the `android` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://blog.csdn.net/sanjinxiong/article/details/6957130)

- First, install android NDK in your computer
- Then download mupdf
  0.8.15 source code(Don't download 1.0 version,without mupdf source code in 1.0.0 )
- Download the thirdparty zip package
  (mupdf-thirdparty-2011-02-24.zip) ,url:mupdf.com//download/archive ,

you will compile successfully.

Comment: [Please provide a summary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115837/158556) for links to pages which are not written in english.

Comment: I can simple translate this page to English.At First , install android NDK in your computer.then download mupdf 0.8.15 source code(Don't download 1.0 version,without mupdf source code in 1.0.0 ) ,and download thirdparty zip package (mupdf-thirdparty-2011-02-24.zip) ,url:http://mupdf.com//download/archive/ ,then compile is so easy.

Comment: @MorrsionMacleo Rather than updated your answer via a comment you can update your answer directly. I took the liberty to demonstrate the editing and layout features for you. If you're not happy with it you can rollback or edit it further