# Swipe pdf pages in horizontally in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application based on pdf reader so  i got opensource pdf reader like 
Vuroid, APV, DroidReader etc.
And i use APV but in that page is scroll vertically but i want to scroll horizontally.
Please help me is it possible or not And if possible give me hint or if any other solution Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya its possible with [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) try this it also provides you

And I think this **[Question Regarding MuPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project)** can also help you to use it.

horizontal scroll, search, and more...