# How to Run a Sample MuPDF in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, mupdf

I am using Windows XP here and Eclipse IDE for development. I did a lot of research on how to use MuPDF and I found this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587527/998732) but I don't know how to do the steps 5 - 7. Then I do another research about MuPDF and found and follow this [Readme.txt](http://mupdf.com/repos/mupdf/android/ReadMe.txt), but I can't get the steps 3 and 6, in step 3 I got an error running the Cygwin, it says Windows if searching for mintty, and in step 6, where can I find the file pregen '**Also get the pregen package from the same place and unpack that into mupdf/pregen.**'.

Does [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com) have a simple step-by-step instruction on how to use it in Android? Or can someone guide me how to use it in Windows and Eclipse IDE ? I am really new to android and I am not familiar with Cygwin, NDK and ANT.

Comment: chk inside mupdf-source/android folder for readme or step-by-step guide

Comment: Check out this SO post. This might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project