# Android MuPDF ndk build Error: No such file or directory

Tags: android

I followed the [steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587527/998732) but I got these errors:

```
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:5:35: error: ../generated/cmap_cns.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:6:34: error: ../generated/cmap_gb.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:7:37: error: ../generated/cmap_japan.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:8:37: error: ../generated/cmap_korea.h: No such file or directory
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:14: error: 'cmap_78_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:15: error: 'cmap_78_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:16: error: 'cmap_78_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:17: error: 'cmap_78_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:18: error: 'cmap_78_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:19: error: 'cmap_78_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:20: error: 'cmap_78ms_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:21: error: 'cmap_78ms_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:22: error: 'cmap_83pv_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:23: error: 'cmap_90ms_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:24: error: 'cmap_90ms_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:25: error: 'cmap_90msp_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:26: error: 'cmap_90msp_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:27: error: 'cmap_90pv_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:28: error: 'cmap_90pv_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:29: error: 'cmap_Add_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:30: error: 'cmap_Add_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:31: error: 'cmap_Add_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:32: error: 'cmap_Add_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:33: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:34: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:35: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:36: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_3' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:37: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_4' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:38: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_5' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:39: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_6' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:40: error: 'cmap_Adobe_CNS1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:41: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:42: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:43: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:44: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_3' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:45: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_4' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:46: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_5' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:47: error: 'cmap_Adobe_GB1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:48: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:49: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:50: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:51: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_3' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:52: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_4' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:53: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_5' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:54: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_6' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:55: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:56: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Japan2_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:57: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_0' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:58: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_1' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:59: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:60: error: 'cmap_Adobe_Korea1_UCS2' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:61: error: 'cmap_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:62: error: 'cmap_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:63: error: 'cmap_B5pc_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:64: error: 'cmap_B5pc_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:65: error: 'cmap_CNS_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:66: error: 'cmap_CNS_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:67: error: 'cmap_CNS1_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:68: error: 'cmap_CNS1_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:69: error: 'cmap_CNS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:70: error: 'cmap_CNS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:71: error: 'cmap_ETHK_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:72: error: 'cmap_ETHK_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:73: error: 'cmap_ETen_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:74: error: 'cmap_ETen_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:75: error: 'cmap_ETenms_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:76: error: 'cmap_ETenms_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:77: error: 'cmap_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:78: error: 'cmap_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:79: error: 'cmap_Ext_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:80: error: 'cmap_Ext_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:81: error: 'cmap_Ext_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:82: error: 'cmap_Ext_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:83: error: 'cmap_GB_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:84: error: 'cmap_GB_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:85: error: 'cmap_GB_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:86: error: 'cmap_GB_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:87: error: 'cmap_GBK_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:88: error: 'cmap_GBK_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:89: error: 'cmap_GBK2K_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:90: error: 'cmap_GBK2K_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:91: error: 'cmap_GBKp_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:92: error: 'cmap_GBKp_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:93: error: 'cmap_GBT_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:94: error: 'cmap_GBT_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:95: error: 'cmap_GBT_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:96: error: 'cmap_GBT_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:97: error: 'cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:98: error: 'cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:99: error: 'cmap_GBpc_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:100: error: 'cmap_GBpc_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:101: error: 'cmap_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:102: error: 'cmap_HKdla_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:103: error: 'cmap_HKdla_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:104: error: 'cmap_HKdlb_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:105: error: 'cmap_HKdlb_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:106: error: 'cmap_HKgccs_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:107: error: 'cmap_HKgccs_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:108: error: 'cmap_HKm314_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:109: error: 'cmap_HKm314_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:110: error: 'cmap_HKm471_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:111: error: 'cmap_HKm471_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:112: error: 'cmap_HKscs_B5_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:113: error: 'cmap_HKscs_B5_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:114: error: 'cmap_Hankaku' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:115: error: 'cmap_Hiragana' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:116: error: 'cmap_Hojo_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:117: error: 'cmap_Hojo_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:118: error: 'cmap_Hojo_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:119: error: 'cmap_Hojo_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:120: error: 'cmap_KSC_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:121: error: 'cmap_KSC_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:122: error: 'cmap_KSC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:123: error: 'cmap_KSC_Johab_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:124: error: 'cmap_KSC_Johab_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:125: error: 'cmap_KSC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:126: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:127: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_HW_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:128: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_HW_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:129: error: 'cmap_KSCms_UHC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:130: error: 'cmap_KSCpc_EUC_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:131: error: 'cmap_KSCpc_EUC_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:132: error: 'cmap_Katakana' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:133: error: 'cmap_NWP_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:134: error: 'cmap_NWP_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:135: error: 'cmap_RKSJ_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:136: error: 'cmap_RKSJ_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:137: error: 'cmap_Roman' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:138: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:139: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:140: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:141: error: 'cmap_UniCNS_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:142: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:143: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:144: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:145: error: 'cmap_UniGB_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:146: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:147: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:148: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:149: error: 'cmap_UniHojo_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:150: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:151: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_HW_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:152: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_HW_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:153: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:154: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:155: error: 'cmap_UniJIS_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:156: error: 'cmap_UniJISPro_UCS2_HW_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:157: error: 'cmap_UniJISPro_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:158: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UCS2_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:159: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UCS2_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:160: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UTF16_H' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:161: error: 'cmap_UniKS_UTF16_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:162: error: 'cmap_V' undeclared here (not in a function)
jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:163: error: 'cmap_WP_Symbol' undeclared here (not in a function)
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o] Error 1
```

Please help me with this. I use ndk-r8 and I compile it using CMD but I got that errors then I follow this [steps to build ndk in eclipse](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/), but still I got the same errors.

**EDITS:** I think this is the main problem here, So where do I get these .h files? I search for this generated directory but found nothing in web. Can someone suggest me where to get these missing .h files?

```
../generated/cmap_cns.h: No such file or directory
../generated/cmap_gb.h: No such file or directory
../generated/cmap_japan.h: No such file or directory
../generated/cmap_korea.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you run make from the item 5? It seems that cmaps have not been generated and I guess this is because of you did not perform item 5 from the tutorial. What OS do you use to perform this tasks?

Comment: @Yury I'm using windows xp. Can you guide me how to perform step number 5?

Comment: I do not know - I use ubuntu ) But I guess you have cygwin installed. Try to launch make for mupdf project from cygwin. (but in readme when you use windows it's recommended to use VS to build the project)

Comment: Thanks @Yury I'll try to install VS and build the project.

Comment: @Yury is there any other way to build the project not using VS?

Comment: I made mupdf using gcc make command. Try to read maybe it's possible to run it on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to go into the `mupdf/` directory (the root of the whole project) and first run `make`. This should generate the `generated/` folder with all needed header files.

Afterwards ndk-build should run without problems.

Answer (score 1):

HI here you can find this all header file .

http://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjni%2Fmupdf%2Fmupdf%2Fgenerated   . 
i have been facing same error like you but after make folder "generated" in parent directory  and copying this headers files , all have solved for me 
,cheer .

Answer (score 0):

First use Visual studio generate.vcproj to generate these header files, then ndk-build.