# Compiling mupdf for android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cygwin, mupdf

have been looking around for a way to build mupdf all around the web. After making much progress and getting so far as building MuPDF generated directory I am stuck on this error while building the library for android.

jni/../../thirdparty/zlib-1.2.5/trees.c: In function 'compress_block':
jni/../../thirdparty/zlib-1.2.5/trees.c:1103: internal compiler error: in reload, at reload1.c:1173
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.
/cygdrive/f/DevJehandad/Android/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-binary.mk:240: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfthirdparty/**/**/thirdparty/zlib-1.2.5/trees.o' failed

Really have no idea how to further on this ... any guidance or hint is welcome.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project/8587527#8587527

Comment: Thanks Yury, your answer and question did helped a lot. But further going down the build I am seeing the "internal Compiler error"...
:S

Comment: Try to read software requirements. Maybe you used a expired compiler or maybe too new compiler.

Comment: Thanks... I was using the third party libs that were downloaded from jmupdf website. When I downloaded them from the right place it compiled fine. I have a java background so I expected that libraries try to maintain there API. This assumption was entirely wrong.