# MuPDF error, on building using ndk-build

Tags: java, android, mupdf, pdfrenderer, vudroid

After a long R.N.D, picking one open source library (i.e MuPDF) for creating PDF VIEWER, but what from last 2week, I found its too not the stable version or don't know what the hell with it, removing errors still getting error over error again.., its my 4th project in my company, I completed 3 project, but this one becomes the bottle neck.

Anyone there to help me? I really thankful!

> - I have removed, '-ljnigraphics' from Android.mk as one answer own
>   stackoverflow, said it is useless so I have, getting no affect!
> - I have remove following lines from Core.mk, because it causing errors and haven't found any solution over those problems, corresponding errors are mentioned below!!

---

### $(MY_ROOT)/draw/draw_simple_scale.c \

> Error: lo register required!

---

### $(MY_ROOT)/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c \

```
cmap_GBpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[9]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4281:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4281:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[9]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4920:2: warning: initialization from incomp
atible pointer type [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4920:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.storable.free') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4921:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4922:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4922:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4922:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4922:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[6]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4922:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4922:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[6]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4923:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4923:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4923:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4923:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[9]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4923:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4923:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_EUC_H.usecmap_name[9]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4941:2: warning: initialization from incomp
atible pointer type [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4941:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_V.storable.free') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4942:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4943:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4943:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[6]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4943:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4943:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[6]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4944:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4944:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[9]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4944:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:4944:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_EUC_V.usecmap_name[9]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5583:2: warning: initialization from incomp
atible pointer type [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5583:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_H.storable.free') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5584:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5585:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5585:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5585:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5585:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[6]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5585:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5585:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[6]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5586:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5586:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5586:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5586:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[9]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5586:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5586:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_H.usecmap_name[9]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5604:2: warning: initialization from incomp
atible pointer type [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5604:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_V.storable.free') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5605:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5606:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5606:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[6]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5606:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5606:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[6]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5607:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5607:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[9]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5607:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:5607:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBT_V.usecmap_name[9]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6246:2: warning: initialization from incomp
atible pointer type [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6246:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.storable.free') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6247:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6248:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6248:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6248:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6248:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[6]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6248:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6248:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[6]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6249:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6249:2: warning: large integer implicitly t
runcated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6249:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6249:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[9]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6249:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6249:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBTpc_EUC_H.usecmap_name[9]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6267:2: warning: initialization from incomp
atible pointer type [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6267:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V.storable.free') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: braces around scalar initi
alizer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: excess elements in scalar
initializer [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6268:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[3]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6269:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6269:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[6]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6269:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6269:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[6]')
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6270:2: warning: initialization makes integ
er from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6270:2: warning: (near initialization for '
cmap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[9]') [enabled by default]
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6270:2: error: initializer element is not c
omputable at load time
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_gb.h:6270:2: error: (near initialization for 'cm
ap_GBTpc_EUC_V.usecmap_name[9]')
In file included from jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:7:0:
jni/../../pdf/../generated/cmap_japan.h:5:1: error: expected '}' before 'static'

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o] Er
ror 1
```

---

### $(MY_ROOT)/pdf/pdf_fontfile.c \

```
jni/../../pdf/pdf_fontfile.c:11:37: fatal error: ../generated/font_droid.h: No s
uch file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_fontfile.o] Erro
r 1
some file
```

---

after removing above three mentioned lines (reference for files) I build and get the following errors..

StaticLibrary  : libmupdfthirdparty.a

SharedLibrary  : libmupdf.so

```
../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdf/mupdf.o: in function Java_co
m_artifex_mupdf_MuPDFCore_drawPage:jni/mupdf.c:178: error: undefined reference t
o 'AndroidBitmap_getInfo'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdf/mupdf.o: in function Java_co
m_artifex_mupdf_MuPDFCore_drawPage:jn/mupdf.c:190: error: undefined reference t
o 'AndroidBitmap_lockPixels'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdf/mupdf.o: in function Java_co
m_artifex_mupdf_MuPDFCore_drawPage:jni/mupdf.c:257: error: undefined reference t
o 'AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(draw_device.o): in function fz
_transform_pixmap:jni/../../draw/draw_device.c:884: error: undefined reference t
o 'fz_scale_pixmap'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(draw_device.o): in function fz
_transform_pixmap:jni/../../draw/draw_device.c:908: error: undefined reference t
o 'fz_scale_pixmap'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(draw_device.o): in function fz
_transform_pixmap:jni/../../draw/draw_device.c:921: error: undefined reference t
o 'fz_scale_pixmap'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(draw_device.o): in function fz
_draw_fill_image:jni/../../draw/draw_device.c:992: error: undefined reference to
 'fz_scale_pixmap'
 
../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_font.o): in function pdf_l
oad_builtin_font:jni/../../pdf/pdf_font.c:184: error: undefined reference to 'pd
f_lookup_builtin_font'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_font.o): in function pdf_l
oad_substitute_font:jni/../../pdf/pdf_font.c:200: error: undefined reference to
'pdf_lookup_substitute_font'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_font.o): in function pdf_l
oad_substitute_cjk_font:jni/../../pdf/pdf_font.c:217: error: undefined reference
 to 'pdf_lookup_substitute_cjk_font'
 
../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_cmap_load.o): in function
pdf_load_system_cmap:jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_load.c:119: error: undefined referen
ce to 'pdf_load_builtin_cmap'

../Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/
windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androidea
bi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmupdfcore.a(pdf_cmap_load.o): in function
pdf_load_system_cmap:jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_load.c:125: error: undefined referen
ce to 'pdf_load_builtin_cmap'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libmupdf.so] Error 1
```

Comment: this link may be useful to you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project 
Try this...

Comment: already gone through this link, after being in searching solution for my errors, i didnt found any solution for 'lo register required!', well i also found that 'generated' folder is where i have to work on for the 3rd error i mentioned above, i saw different answers but nobody answered how to run 'make' command.

Comment: I tried to run make command in root folder of mupdf (extracted folder) [using cgywin] but error occurs 

>$ make
CC build/debug/ft_ftbase.o
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/cc1.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygppl_c-2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makethird:50: recipe for target `build/debug/ft_ftbase.o' failed
make: *** [build/debug/ft_ftbase.o] Error 1

Comment: anybody out there??? to help me out

Comment: hey were you able to find the solution to the `lo register problem`, am building on mac terminal

Answer (score 1):

I was getting your exact same problem until I used the R6 version of the Android NDK.

I got it from the Android website by simply changing 'r8d' to 'r6' in the URL.

For OSX: http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r6-darwin-x86.tar.bz2

Windows: http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r6-windows.zip

Linux: http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r6-linux-x86.tar.bz2

I hope that helps.