# Unable to Build MUPDF Library in Windows Envirenoment for Android

Tags: android, pdf, sdk, android-ndk, mupdf

I know that there is MUPDF library   available under GPL licence for rendering PDF files in android. This library contains native code. For Native code compilation we need android NDK. and CYGWIN tool.

I have Dowloaded a MUPDF library code from code.google.com site. I have also downloaded and installed the android-NDK and CYGWIN tool.  I have started to build MUPDF library by Following steps mentioned on different forums.

But when i build my application by using these steps [Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project/8587527#8587527)

But fail to compile successfully, therefor when i run my project it's thrown exception on this line in library code

```
System.LoadLibrary(mupdfc);
```

I need help regarding this issue. I am using window XP.

Comment: the spelling of your question is one thing, the spelling of your code is another... (and i'm not sure i understand what you would like to express about yourself by using this particular avatar)

Comment: @njzk2 In simple words that i am unable to Build MUPDF library (Used for PDF Rendering in android).

Comment: You are using the latest version of mypdf? I recomend you using latest version from mupdf repository.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, when you fail to build the library, the library load will fail and the project won't work.

Asking us why the library build fails without supplying any error messages or diagnostic information is unlikely to get you any useful answers.