# android mupdf build cannot find -ljbig2dec

Tags: mupdf

i follow this [step] ([Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project/8587527#8587527))! and i get this error in cygwin. please help...i'm stuck

```
ASUS@ASUS-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/ASUS/Documents/resources/Library/mupdf-0.9
$ make generate
CC build/debug/cmapdump.o
LINK build/debug/cmapdump
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ljbig2dec
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:46: recipe for target `build/debug/cmapdump' failed
make: *** [build/debug/cmapdump] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the "thirdparty" code as included in the mupdf repo? If not, you probably ought to be (especially for cross compiling). In your git repo:

"git submodule update --init"

should get the third party sources.