# How to render pdf within the android application using PDF library

Tags: android, pdf-rendering

I searched a lot on PDF rendering but not get proper answer.can anyone tell me which library (licensed under GPL) to render PDF and how to render that PDF.
  If anyone has sample code then it will be more helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mupdf

http://www.mupdf.com/

MuPDF is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the Affero GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

Here's a link i found on SO. List of few pdf libraries helful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android/4766335#4766335

Comment: I have already tried MuPDF but while building library getting error can please post steps to build library and integrate it into my android project .need your quick replay.

Comment: now, I have compiled the muPDF library and installed the test android application . It is running.

Followed the instructions given in the mupdf documentation

Comment: PDF parsing library for Android? this link helped me alot

Comment: so mupdf is the only GPL library ...think not !!

Comment: @MauricioGracia not sure i posted this answer very long ago. If there is something you want to add up please edit the post.

Comment: @Raghunandan see my answer below and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two choices

Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Mupdf 
http://www.mupdf.com/

MuPDF is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the Affero GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

**See also**
[Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/integrate-mupdf-reader-in-an-app/8587527#8587527)