# Flip horizontally like flipboard with MuPDF

Tags: android, mupdf

I have implemented the **MuPDf** in android to **open**,**view**,**search**,**setting bookmarks** etc for a **PDF**. Now i want the animation effect of horizontal flip i.e. similar to be like used in the FlipBoard Application in horizontal manner.

I also need to know that how can i highlight the Search Text. I am using [Librelio's code](https://github.com/libreliodev/android)

I have gone through the links Like:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/mupdf-reader-integrate-in-project)

Please help.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?! means Flip/curl horizontally with MuPDF.

Comment: Did you solve the flipping animation problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 I also need to know that how can i highlight the Search Text.
```

PageView.java of MuPDF:

```
private static final int HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 0x802572AC; //adjust the color

...//some code of PageView.java

public void setPage(int page, PointF size) {

 ...//code of PageView.setPage(int page, PointF size)

 // this is the part where the hightlighting happens
 if (!mIsBlank && mSearchBoxes != null) {
   paint.setColor(HIGHLIGHT_COLOR);
   for (RectF rect : mSearchBoxes)
   canvas.drawRect(rect.left*scale, rect.top*scale,
   rect.right*scale, rect.bottom*scale, paint);

   // you can customize it, e.g. 
   // int margin = 5
   //canvas.drawRect((rect.left - margin) * scale, (rect.top - margin) * scale,
   //(rect.right + margin) * scale, (rect.bottom + margin) * scale, paint);
 }
}
```

to start a search, just invoke:

```
new SearchTask(context, mupdfCore).go("searchText", 1, 0, -1);
```