# Android View PDF with form

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-form

I need to view some PDF files with embeded form and process values that user inputs in form. Does anyone have such experience? Can you suggest library for it or another solution. I cannot use GPL solutions, because my apps will be proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use mu-pdf library.If you want to use MUPDF inside an existing android app project you can follow the guide you find at [this link](http://mupdf.blogspot.com) (all credits go to the author, I didn't write this).

Also, as we both (if I understood correctly your needs) need just the PDF rendering features, would be great if someone points out how to (if possible) disable some of the unnecessary features built in the MuPDF library when building it from source (as DjVu support, just as an example).

GITHUB --> https://github.com/muennich/mupdf

*take note that is not free for commercial apps –*

check this for better help -->[Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/integrate-mupdf-reader-in-an-app)

---

## update

Some of the source code files for PDF viewer in Android application. Check the links and try it:

http://code.google.com/p/apv/source/browse/

http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/

http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/

http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It seems to have GPL license. I can't use it in my proprietary projects