# Android NDK: No rule to make target with MuPDF

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, mupdf

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/integrate-mupdf-reader-in-an-app/17735927#17735927) link, the answer by [star18bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766855/star18bit), to integrate MuPDF with my Android project.

I am able to run the `ndk-build` that is inside the MuPDF's android folder. But when I copied all MuPDF's files to my own project, and ran `ndk-build` from my project's jni folder, it gives this error:

`make: *** No rule to make target ../jni/fitz/base_context.c', needed by ../jni/fitz/base_context.o'.  Stop.`

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

I am following this link as it is, i.e., using the mupdf version 1.2 and android ndk r8e

Comment: So is there a `fitz/base_context.c` under `jni`?

Comment: @Michael Yes, there is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to build this on MAC, but gave up.

Finally I did it on Windows 7, encountered a lot of issues while doing it. So I made a tutorial for it, for other users so that they don't have to go through the pain that I went through!

Here's the link:

http://howtojava.net/tutorials/android/integrate-mupdf-with-android-in-windows-7

Comment: It is under maintenance, will be up soon

Comment: Please make the link active soon. I need help