# mupdf library / classes usage pains -- Android

Tags: android, c, pdf, mupdf

After going through a lot of trouble (and pain) to get the mupdf library files (StaticLibrary  : libmupdfthirdparty.a, SharedLibrary  : libmupdf.so)
I was prepared to begin using it to browse pdf files. At this stage I only need to display a specific pages from a pdf file.

Some info on the net suggest that I should go through a lot of steps (see answer #7 on [Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/integrate-mupdf-reader-in-an-app)).

But these steps seem to be such a cumbersome and fruitless way to go about incorporating a library or third party software into a project. It just seems so dumb.

Are these steps really necessary?

Furthermore, there is so little info on the usage of the library itself... There is a simple example in C code in the mupdf project with a function 
render(...). This is a good example; but I do know how access it in Android code.

I need to be able to use the functions in the mupdf library in a simple manner; initially to display a specific page of a pdf file

How can I use this library/ where do I find info on its usage?

Thank you.