# PDF Rendering issue in Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-pdf-api

I am using https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview to render PDFs in android. It shows pdf file with grey box, how can I fix this ? please click the attached link to see image

Are there any free pdf rendering library for android?

Thanks

[PDF image with grey box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP4cp.png)

Comment: If you could supply an example PDF, we can have a look at why this happens. In all likelihood it is because your viewer doesn't support one of the features in your PDF file. By the way - don't ask "are there any free tools..."; questions about tools to use are off-topic for StackOverflow and will get your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two choices

Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Mupdf 
http://www.mupdf.com/

MuPDF is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the Affero GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

For more details

[Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/integrate-mupdf-reader-in-an-app/8587527#8587527)