# Converting PDF to text and reading it from android

Tags: android

I am currently working on an android application that will allow people to read the constitution, issue is I have only managed to get my hands on a soft copy pdf document. Ideally, I wanted an API that would allow me to fetch the document by Topic, issue or paragraph, I thought of multiple ways of getting the job done

```
 1. Is by putting the document on the server, when user opens the app it downloads the pdf and allows them to read it(Problem with this is I won't be able to mess with the content like bold some text etc).
 2. Is copying the content of the pdf into the databse and just fetching the text with a query(issue with this is I wont be able to do pagination given I put the content in one field)
```

Here is the link to the [Constitution](http://www.parliament.gov.zm/sites/default/files/documents/amendment_act/Constitution%20of%20Zambia%20(Amendment)%2C%202016-Act%20No.%202_0.pdf) I needed a way in which I can load the data from the database in a way that I will be able to paginate, load a single paragraph or topic at a time. Can anyone whose been in a similar situation help me figure out the best way possible.

Comment: How about I convert the document to Html? I mean that will handle most of my problems wont it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't to convert it to text, you can integrate MuPdf in your application check this answer I've found [integrating pdf reader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587527/4967534)

Comment: that is like option 1, the problem with it is I wont be able to mess with the text, Incase I want to fetch content by title or word from the document it wont be possible

Comment: if you want to mess with the text, you can mess it manually before uploading it to a server.