# I want to open .pdf file in my application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to open a document file in Android application with help of Android studio. How can be possible? Should I need to use web view? I had try source code from many webs but file was opened by other application

Comment: show your code what you tried.

Comment: You can use a library for it too.. https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: You need to integrate MuPDf in your application.
Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/integrate-mupdf-reader-in-an-app/8587527#8587527)

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: read answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820255/12980819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open pdf files using **Intents**.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/example.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you dont like this method, and want to open pdf files inside your application, you can use a custom **PDF Viewer**.

In your **gradle file** *compile* this: `'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'`

After you **sync** your project, go to your xml file and add the **PDF Viewer**.

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView android:id="@+id/pdfView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now in your *.java* file you will import:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;
 
import java.util.List;
```

You will *Implement* two methods: `OnPageChangeListener` and `OnLoadCompleteListener`

MAIN CODE:

```
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf"; //your file path
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
 
        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }
 
    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;
 
        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true) 
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }
 
 
    @Override
     public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
    }
 
 
    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");
 
    }
 
    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {
            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thats it!

> P.S: First search on google, if you dont find something, write your
> question!

Comment: Thanks,Great Work. but  I am accessing pdf files from server. So how can i open it with URL?

Comment: I am not sure but you can write in `SAMPLE_FILE` the url of pdf you want _e.x. https://www.mywebsite.com/pdfs/myFile.pdf_