# Create right to left PDF file in Android

Tags: java, android, pdf, right-to-left

Can anyone recommend an android java library that creates PDF files and support right to left reading order languages such as Arabic and Hebrew?
Or a way to create them using libraries such as PdfBox-Android, apwlibrary ?
iText is ok but 0.5$ per device is too expensive for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called MuPDF which support RTL (Right to Left) writing and it is open source!

[Link of MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/)

[Integrate MuPDF Reader in an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500530/integrate-mupdf-reader-in-an-app)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is online then you could use a document service like [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) to create the documents and stream them to your app.  The up sides are that there is little coding to do (document templates) and all the processing is offloaded to your servers (or the Docmosis cloud servers).  You would have to consider fonts Arabic and Hebrew and the right-to-left should work.  The down sides are that it's not free (but might not be expensive depending on your scale of use) and your app needs to be online to create the document.  Please note I work for Docmosis.